# Magento remove decimals from product page

Tags: magento, decimal

I have implemented the following changes to remove decimals from the product price:
app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php
change 2 -> 0

www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php
change 2 -> 0

However, when the product has a custom option, the price appears with decimals (i.e. 1,600.00). Any suggestions on how to remove the decimals when the product has a custom option?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I use ET Currency Manager module and so far it works very nice. It can handle the 00 and a lot more with prices. You can get it free and magento connect. Here's the link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to js/varien/js.js in root

and update

```
 var precision = isNaN(format.precision = Math.abs(format.precision)) ? 2 : format.precision;
 var requiredPrecision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision;
```

by

```
var precision = 0;
var requiredPrecision = 0;
```